# Check nuxt-child is empty or not

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Is there any way to check `nuxt-child` or native `router-view` has childs or not? for instance I wanted to show a div if `nuxt-child` was empty/or didn't not set.

```
<div v-if=" nuxt-child == null ">
   Choose something to start...
</div>

<nuxt-child />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe if you can use the $emit function to pass to parent component some data. 
for instance, on created function, make any tests, and if the test are null return false.
This way can be? Maybe I can provide some code to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the [matched components](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/v2.13.3/packages/vue-app/template/utils.js#L90) for the routes.

```
<div v-if="this.$route.matched.length">
   Choose something to start...
</div>
```